# email already exist validation in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
$('#cemail').on('blur', function () {

    var email = $(this).val();
    var dataPosting = 'cemail=' + email;
    console.log(email + '  ' + dataPosting);

    $.ajax({
        method: "post",
        data: dataPosting,
        url: 'check_dup_email.php',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (parseInt(data) === 1) {
                $('#email_status').html('Email already used');
                $('#cemail').focus();
                console.log('Already Exists');
            } else {
                console.log('carry on');
                $('#email_status').html('');
            }

        }
```

i tried email validation for my form...i want to show email already exist where enter email id which is in database already...? please anyone help me?

Comment: what's the content of check_dup_email.php ?

Comment: Where is the problem ?

Comment: where is your php code and SELECT statement?

Comment: Please show your PHP page code.

Answer (score 0):

you should change the ajax code.your were **comparing wrong value in response**.just **change compare value in ajax code**.

```
$.ajax({
    method: "post",
    data: {
            cemail : email
           },
    url: 'check_dup_email.php',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        if ((data) == "equal") {
            $('#email_status').html('Email already used');
            $('#cemail').focus();
            console.log('Already Exists');
        } else {
            console.log('carry on');
            $('#email_status').html('');
        }

    }
});
```

php code :

```
<?php 
    include_once("init.php");
    include_once'dbconfig.php';  
    //$email=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'cemail'); 
    $query="select * from stock_sales where st_email='purender@gmail.com' "; 
     $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
     $count=mysqli_num_rows($result); 
       if($count===1){ echo "equal"; } else{ echo "not equal"; }
```

?>

Comment: `var dataPosting = 'cemail=' + email;` its valid.. or can u explain `AN ISSUE?`

Comment: @devpro are you able to get data in php ?try with fire bug to check response of php file

Comment: `'cemail=' + email;` just a param, i am not talking about the response. open FireBug, check post data.

Comment: but still waiting for OP response.

Comment: <?php
include_once("init.php");
include_once'dbconfig.php';

//$email=filter_input(INPUT_POST,'cemail');

$query="select * from stock_sales where st_email='purender@gmail.com' ";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($count===1){
   echo "equal";
}
else{
   echo "not equal";
}
?>

Comment: the above file is my php file